# How to track apps running in background in objective c

Tags: ios

I am trying to develop an app that tracks apps running in the background mode.Please guide me that if is possible. if yes,please provide some code snippets.

Answer (score 0):

To get you going: the Terminal command `top` shows you a list of running processes. You can discover how it obtains the information it displays from its source which Apple makes available at [top source](https://opensource.apple.com/source/top/top-108/). If you poke around elsewhere in Apple's open source site you'll probably also find the source of `ps`. HTH